# Changing background color of listview c# when disabled

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, .net-2.0

How to change the background color of a Listview Control in C#  when the Control is disabled??

The color of a textbox can be changed when it is disabled but when a listview is disabled it goes grey and we can't apply any color to it.So is there a way to change background color of Listview control when disabled??

Answer (score 4):

I've tried with overriding `OnPaint`, `OnPaintBackground` but the `BackColor` is still no change. Even `WM_PAINT` can change it but the Item backcolor is not identical to the listview BackColor. I had thought of this solution before although it is just some kind of hack but it seems to be the only working solution, the whole idea is to use a `Background Image` instead:

```
    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(listView1.ClientSize.Width, listView1.ClientSize.Height);
    Graphics.FromImage(bm).Clear(listView1.BackColor);
    listView1.BackgroundImage = bm;
```

If you want to create your own `ListView` which supports BackColor in disabled state, here is the class:

```
public class MyListView : ListView {
   public override Color BackColor {
      get { return base.BackColor;}
      set {
        base.BackColor = value;
        if(BackgroundImage == null){
           Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(1,1);
           bm.SetPixel(0,0,value);
           BackgroundImage = bm;
           BackgroundImageTiled = true;
        }
      }
   }
   public override Image BackgroundImage {
      get { return base.BackgroundImage; }
      set {
          base.BackgroundImage = value;
          if(value == null){
            Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(1,1);
            bm.SetPixel(0,0,BackColor);
            BackgroundImage = bm;
            BackgroundImageTiled = true;  
          }
      }
   }
}
```

If someone has another solution, I would like to know also.

Comment: I took a different approach.I just disabled the events on the listview (drag drop,click event) on set of a bool property stating  to disable it.So the listview doesn't go grey and also the functionality like drag drop,click are all disabled.